# Plotting pie charts for nominal variables in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pie-chart, finance

So I have a DataFrame with 3 columns, about bond markets: Year issued(numerical and only year, no dates), Size(numerical), Type(nominal, total of 5). I would like to plot a pie chart for only a specific year (last one, 2020, I have data since 1996) with respect to Type. In short, I want a pie chart that will **show me percentages of every type of bond in total bond issuance in 2020.**

I have tried query, groupby methods but they didn't work. I did manage to get a pie chart, but since I didn't specify a certain year, I am pretty sure that chart refers to the type of bond during the whole time period.

I hope you guys can help me. Thank you all in advance!

Best regards

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured it out. For those who were wondering, this is the code I used:

df.query("Date == 2020").groupby('Type').sum().plot(y='Size',kind='pie', fontsize=13)

Comment: You need to provide some sample data such as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easy for us to help you.